# Weird results using chrome and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, timer, updatepanel

I am building an online radio station that uses an update panel with a timer trigger.  When the timer fires, the code behind updates labels and images.  It works fine in FireFox and IE but when viewing the site in Chrome, the page appears to be reloading the entire site so it looks like flicker.  The site is http://maxradio.stormtechnologies.biz

ASP.Net Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="25000" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="StockPricePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Table ID="MainTable" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="100%">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Top" Width="320px">
                    <asp:Table ID="PlayingNow" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%">
                        <asp:TableRow BackColor="#4B6C9E"><asp:TableCell Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Size="Small">Now Playing</asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <asp:Image ID="Cover" runat="server" Height="300px" ImageAlign="Middle" Width="300px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <asp:Label ID="song" runat="server" Text="empty" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label ID="artist" runat="server" Text="empty" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label><br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                    </asp:Table>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbCon.iSongOld = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);

        SQL = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM historylist";
        dbCon.sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, dbCon.sqlCon);
        dbCon.iID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        SQL = "SELECT songID FROM historylist WHERE (ID = '" + dbCon.iID + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(SQL, dbCon.sqlCon);
        dbCon.iSong = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
        dbCon.sqlCon.Close();

        if (dbCon.iSong == dbCon.iSongOld)
            Label1.Text = dbCon.iSongOld.ToString();
        else
        {
        Label1.Text = dbCon.iSong.ToString();
        GetPlayingInfo(dbCon.iSong);
        GetQuedSongs();
        GetTopFive();
        GetRecentSongs();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I checked  your site and found an error in chrome ( only in chrome) the error is GET http://99.95.52.156:8000/;stream/1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT .

Comment: My bad...I did not have the streamer running.  I will start that and let it run.  If you check again I think you may see the issue I am having.  The site is now streaming so that error will not happen.

Comment: Update - Also does this in Safari.